# How do you get struct-copy to create a struct of the same type as the original?

Tags: struct, racket

To illustrate, here's a little immutable struct and a function to update it:

```
(struct timeseries (variable observations) #:transparent)

(define (add-observation ts t v)
  (struct-copy timeseries ts
               [observations (conj (timeseries-observations ts) `(,t ,v))]))
```

My question is: If I make a struct that inherits from `timeseries`, then `add-observation` will return a `timeseries` struct rather than a struct of the type that it was passed. How do you update a struct and retain its type?

By the way, if the above code is just not how things are done in Racket, please let me know the conventional way. The fact that I haven't found a function in the Racket libraries like [`struct-copy`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/struct-copy.html?q=inspector#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct-copy%29%29) but that retains the type of the original struct makes me suspect that I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there some ordinary way to accomplish the same purpose without encountering the problem of returning a struct of a different type than you started with?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible (unless you change what struct-inheritance means). You might have to live with the fact that you will get a `timeseries` struct only. Also, are you actively using struct-inheritance now, or is this just a general worry that struct-inheritance _later_ could mess it up?

Comment: @AlexKnauth I'm not actively using struct inheritance now. I'm just starting to learn Racket. I want to get started on the right foot, by learning conventional good practice right away. I do have many years' experience programming in other languages, and `struct-copy`'s first argument "smells" like a bug-generator—probably something I shouldn't get into the habit of using. Is there a more Rackety way of doing this?

Comment: @AlexKnauth I had the good fortune to talk with @samth. I got the impression that struct's in Racket are meant as a very low-level data structure, whereas I was viewing them as somewhat comparable to classes in OO languages. Could the right answer be something like this?—"If you've got a bunch of different kinds of struct that you're (functionally) updating, then you also need to write some code to choose the appropriate type of struct to create when it calls `struct-copy`."

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of `struct-copy`'s well-known limitations, most of which stem from it being implemented by what Sam Tobin-Hochstadt has aptly [described](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/N8YXbjh3j88/nK9ZQItEzvUJ) as "unhygenically pasting bits of structs together" (rather than a low-level notion of copying structs), and is part of the [reason](https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/1399) that "`struct-copy` is hopeless and can't be fixed without major changes to how structs work." Matthias Felleisen [described](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/mcfXx0rqtKY/Dt65n3MHsxUJ) this as "an Achilles' heel in our world." There is definitely a desire in the Racket community to improve this situation, but for a number of reasons it seems  daunting. I'm not aware of anyone actively working on it, and what a principled solution would look like seems to be an open question.

Structs are in many ways very fundamental to Racket. Conceptually, every value in Racket could be an instance of some struct type, though in reality the runtime system has specialized representations for certain built-ins. In fact, I think the ongoing work of replacing C with Chez Scheme in the Racket implementation may use structs for some things that are built-ins in the legacy Racket VM. This is possible because structs offer strong encapsulation capabilities, especially through [inspectors](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/inspectors.html). Improving the way structs work would touch essentially all of Racket and involve many disparate considerations, especially around backwards-compatibility.

Here are a few pointers for further reading about the issues:

- [This message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/lSrdJM8sDPU/YP8aLNWQSZ4J) from Sam sketches out how `struct` could start providing more static information while preserving backwards compatibility.
- [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/1399), particularly the last comment from Alexis, points out (a) that it isn't obvious what the right static information to add would be  and (b) that adding static information about the field names wouldn't be enough to solve the subtyping issues.
- [This thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/racket-users/TCWO53qPHBk/discussion) points out a different limitation of `struct-copy` and includes a good summary from Alexis:

  > … `struct-copy` is irreparably broken and cannot be fixed without
  >   fundamental changes to Racket’s struct system. Namely, it has the
  >   “slicing” problem familiar to C++ programmers when using struct
  >   inheritance, and the way it synthesizes field accessors from the
  >   provided field names is unhygienic and can be easily thwarted.

The good news is that, while figuring out The Right Thing to do the general case is hard, Racket's languages-as-libraries approach makes it possible for all programmers and library-writers to try different approaches in their own code. There are various Racket packages to help with functional update and other features. Alexis' [`struct-update`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/struct-update/index.html) provides a macro to synthesize functions like `timeseries-observations-update`. Jay McCarthy has also experimented with [enhancements to struct](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/racket-users/mcfXx0rqtKY/vs9TBGM1PcIJ) in library code. You can also implement a solution tailored to your specific use-case, ranging from implementing a consistent `copy` method (with `racket/generic` or `racket/class`) to creating a domain-specific language that can more naturally express your problem domain. [This mailing-list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/racket-users/fMt8Fw0O7zM/discussion), despite the subject line, covers a lot of approaches to functional update in Racket (including some thoughts from me about DSLs).

Answer (score 3):

Answer from 2022: "unhygenically pasting bits of structs together" and "struct-copy is hopeless and can't be fixed without major changes to how structs work." which were referring to the hygiene problems, are no longer true. These problems have been mostly fixed.

For the original post's problem (which is not really related to the hygiene issues), it remains difficult to solve this problem with function abstraction. However, if we are allowed to use syntactic abstraction, we can do the following:

```
#lang racket

(struct timeseries (variable observations) #:transparent)

(define-syntax-rule (add-observation id ts t v)
  (struct-copy id ts
               [observations
                #:parent timeseries
                (cons (list t v) (timeseries-observations ts))]))

(struct good-timeseries timeseries (goodness) #:transparent)

(define val (good-timeseries 'id (list (list 1 2)) "goodness value"))

(add-observation good-timeseries
                 val
                 10 11)

;=> (good-timeseries 'id '((10 11) (1 2)) "goodness value")
```

Here, `add-observation` is changed to be a macro, and it accepts a struct transformation binding as the first argument, which allows `struct-copy` to produce a struct of the desired type.

Comment: It's nice to hear that the hygiene issues with `struct-copy` have mostly been fixed! Now a question about this solution: Must the first argument to add-observation be the struct definition? If so, it sounds like code that received a timeseries struct, without knowing that it's really a `good-timeseries`, would not be able to call `add-observation` to get a `good-timeseries`—i.e. you couldn't write generic code that did the right thing on a timeseries regardless of inheritance. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Sorawee Porncharoenwase's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72149432/10871073) a bit, there are some shenanigans you can pull to get closer to what it seems is desired, and can be made (pretty) generic.

Consider the following scenario, with a single parent struct type `animal`, with 2 children `snake` and `dog`.

```lisp
#lang racket

(struct animal (has-fur? leg-count) #:transparent)
(struct snake animal (color) #:transparent)
(struct dog animal (breed) #:transparent)
```

We can use `define-syntax-rule` to create a macro-expansion-style function that checks against different possible instances, calling `(struct-copy ...)` on the relevant child struct.

```lisp
(define-syntax-rule (update-base-animal an [t #:parent animal v] ...)
  (cond [(snake? an)
         (struct-copy snake an [t #:parent animal v]...)]
        [(dog? an)
         (struct-copy dog an [t #:parent animal v]...)]
        ; if you want to disallow updating a plain animal instance
        [else (error (~s "Invalid animal" an))]))
```

Once this is defined (and, keep in mind, updated as you potentially add more child struct types) it can be called with any parent updates.

```lisp
; dogs learn to walk on 2 legs
(update-base-animal (dog #t 4 "Golden Retriever")
                    [leg-count #:parent animal 2])
;- (dog #t 2 "Golden Retriever")

; snakes grow fur and legs
(update-base-animal (snake #f 0 "Brown")
                    [has-fur? #:parent animal #t]
                    [leg-count #:parent animal 2])
;- (snake #t 2 "Brown")
```

Note that, with how this is written, every update run through this macro has to be on a parent of the given struct (and be marked with `#:parent`). There's probably a way to do this so that parent and child updates can be intermingled, but this was enough to fulfil my use-case so I stopped there :)